# Mounting external hard drive makes all new files or pasted files with 777 permissions, how to change that?

Tags: permissions, mount, devices

I've looked all over and I can't find the answer to fix this. I also recognize I may not know the exact terms to use to search for this issue.

So, I automount my external hard drive using:

```
udisksct1 mount --block-device /dev/disk/by-uuid/<uuid>
```

Replacing uuid with the actual id.

When I create a new file (e.g. with `touch`) or paste a file into this device, the file starts with the permission 777... but I don't want that! At most I would like 666. How do I make it so the new files or pasted files *always* get created as 666? I've read several places to just use `chmod 666 -R *` etc, but I don't want to do this every time.

*Notes*: Running `df -T` shows that the hard drive is `ext4`. Not sure if that is important. I am using Ubuntu 16.04 LTS, but using the i3 window manager. Because of this I need to automount on my own since Nautilus doesn't start by default. This hard drive will not likely be used by anyone but me. The `umask` is `0022`.

Comment: try read https://superuser.com/questions/519824/mounting-ext4-drive-with-specified-user-permission and https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/33330/how-to-make-an-ext4-file-writable-on-mounting-by-a-user-not-root

Comment: @Alex_Krug those help me mount the drive, but so far it doesn't fix the problem of all files being created as 777...